# Why vector comparision result shows error when not put in parenthesis?

Tags: c++, vector

In the following code, I was getting lot of errors. When I use cout << (v1 > v2) << endl instead, all the errors disappeared and I get the correct output. Why is this so?
Here is the first part of the error I got (there were lot of errors but if needed I will post all of them):

```
abc.cpp: In function 'int main()':

abc.cpp:18:10: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::vector<int>')
```

and me code is:

```
/* #include <bits/stdc++.h> */

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

//using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::sort;

int main(void)
{
    vector <int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
    vector <int> v2 = {1, 2, 5};
    cout << v1 > v2 << endl;

    // free variables
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules? Hint: `<<` comes before `<`, so you're actually asking for `(cout << v1) > (v2 << endl)`

Comment: It is about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Without parenthesis you get `(cout << v1) > (v2 << endl)`

Comment: This is because `<<` was originally only left-shift, and `1 << 2 > 1 << 3` should be `(1 << 2) > (1 << 3)`. This had some unfortunate effect when it was adopted as the stream insertion operator.

Comment: Actually I'm new to C++ and used to use C before this.. Never faced this problem with C so I missed it here:/

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you need the paratheses is because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  `>` has lower precedence than `<<` so

```
cout << v1 > v2 << endl;
```

is actually

```
(cout << v1) > (v2 << endl);
```

which is why you get an error.