# Why isn't the OR (||) logical operator being properly computed?

Tags: c++, logical-operators, cout, operator-precedence, shift

When printing to the terminal, the OR operator is not being applied in C++.

### [MWE](https://www.onlinegdb.com/sdZaX3W4D):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << false || true;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @teapot418 :face-palm: you are right, hope this is not too dumb for SO

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75034962/why-vector-comparision-result-shows-error-when-not-put-in-parenthesis

Comment: The lesson to learn is always add ( ) so you never get it wrong  :)

Comment: Unless the brackets make it wrong. But if programming were easy everybody would be doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift operators have higher priority than logical operators.

So this statement

```
std::cout << false || true;
```

is equivalent to

```
( std::cout << false ) || ( true );
```

As a result the literal `false` will be outputted as integer `0`.

If you want to output the literal `true` then you should write

```
std::cout << ( false || true );
```

Comment: The answer is correct. To a novice the operator precedence in this case is probably surprising. If the `<<` operator was invented as a streaming operator it would have had lower precedence, but its original and alternative use as a bit-shift operator means that it has the precedence that it has. This is a general issue with operator overloading. As the answer illustrates, better use too many parenthesis than too few. I often put redundant parenthesis so that code can be understood without cross-checking the precedence table.